# Sort a list of Int pairs by the difference of the values (a, b)

Tags: haskell, tuples, list-comprehension, quicksort

How do I sort a `list` of `Int` pairs by the difference of the values `|first - second|` in an ascending order?

For calculating the difference I wrote this piece of code:

```
ab :: (Int, Int) -> Int
ab (x, y) = if x - y >= 0 then (x - y)
            else (x - y) * (-1)
```

I wanted to use `quicksort` on the values I get:

```
sort :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
sort [] = []
sort (x:xs) = sort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ sort larger
          where smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
                larger = [a | a <- xs, a > x]
```

The problem is how do I build my `ab` function into `the` sort function? I have tried several ways but always got compiler errors.

Comment: What's `smallerOrEqual`? What type does it have? Can you write a function using `ab` that fits that type?

Comment: `smallerOrEqual` has the same type like the `sort` function: `[(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]`. I don't know how to write `ab` in a way to make it fit into my `sort` function. Because while `ab` is for pairs I work in `sort` with list of pairs. I'm new to haskell and it confuses me a lot :(

Comment: The definition of `smallerOrEqual` is in the `sort` function.
See in the `where` statement:
`where smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]`

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did the attempts give?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit to fast on the trigger, there :$

Comment: Try to remove the type declaration of `sort` and see what that gives you. Then consider passing `smallerOrEqual` and `larger` as arguments to the `sort` function. Can you implement `larger` as the Boolean negation of `smallerOrEqual`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do that with the standard library functions only!

First of all, there is a generic version of sorting function named `sortBy` (I'll show the types of relevant functions as we go, using GHCi's brilliant `:t` command):

```
ghci> import Data.List
ghci> :t sortBy
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

First parameter of `sortBy` suggests that to compare elements we need a *sorting predicate* — a function which takes two elements of the list and tells if the first one is greater. In many cases, yours included, you don't have to define such a function by yourself. Instead, you can use a function which “*measures*” how important an element of a list is. E.g. you have an element of a list `(x,y)` and its measure is `|x-y|` — this is exactly your `ab` function, but remember that we want it to be defined via standard ones.

For now, we have two tasks: 1) define measure function of type `(Int, Int) -> Int`; 2) learn how to turn it into into a sorting predicate. I told that the the latter one is trivial, as it can be done via standard function `comparing`:

```
ghci> import Data.Ord
ghci> :t comparing
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
```

So what I'm suggesting is that `comparing ab` is a perfect match for the first argument of `sortBy`. Not let's turn to the other task: defining `ab` via standard functions.

Consider the type of `-` function:

```
ghci> :t (-)
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

If you substitute `Int` for the `a`(¹) you get nearly the type you want to have, i.e. `Int -> Int -> Int`. Here we hit very frequent task of turning a function from two arguments (`(-)`) into a function acting on pairs. Luckily, there is a standard function for doing this, namely, `uncurry`:

```
ghci> :t uncurry (-)
uncurry (-) :: Num c => (c, c) -> c
```

That's what we need! Now we just have to pipe it with the `abs` function which computes `|·|`, and we are good. We compose functions be means of `.`. Resulting solution is this one:

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord  (comparing)

sortAbsPairs :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
sortAbsPairs = sortBy (comparing $ abs . uncurry (-))
```

You can try it out in GHCi assuming you saved it in `sort.hs`:

```
ghci>:l sort.hs
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> sortAbsPairs [(8,20), (5, 10), (1,2)]
    [(1, 2), (5, 10), (8, 20)]
```

---

(¹) You actually can ask GHCi to substitute types for type parameters of functions by setting up a language extension called `TypeApplications`:

```
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
ghci> :t (-) @Int
(-) @Int :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Answer (score 3):

While `sortBy` is well-known, it is mostly accompanied by `comparing`. You can use `sortOn` instead. `sortOn` has the advantage that it uses the Schwartzian transform, i.e. it only computes the difference once for each element.

```
--Prelude Data.List> :t sortOn
--sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]

import Data.List(sortOn)
sort = sortOn (abs . uncurry (-))
```

But if you really want to use your original sort, pattern match the pairs:

```
sort ((x,x'):xs) = [ (a,a') | (a,a') <- xs, -- ... your homework here
```

I extend the homework part at a later point to make it a full answer.